# How can i find all the lists from a nested list that contains a keyword from another list

Tags: python, find, contains, nested-lists, cpu-word

I can't find a way out to get all the desired lists from a nested list that contains words from another list. My nested list is a bag of words from texts.

This is a snippet of my nested list :

```
[['what',
  'selection',
  'in',
  'dhaka'],
 ['emergency',
  'donors',
  'in',
  'kotwali',
  'posts'],
 ['the',
  'threat',
  'monsoon',
  'progresses',
  'hitting',
  ]
```

This is a snippet of my list with which I want to compare/check (`comparable_lst`) :

```
['dhaka',
 'kotwali',
 'khilkhet',
 'khilgaon',
 'demra',
 'turag']
```

I tried out this

```
[i for e in bag_of_words for i in comparable_lst if e in i]
```

My expected result is:

```
[['what',
  'selection',
  'in',
  'dhaka'],
 ['emergency',
  'donors',
  'in',
  'dhaka',
  'posts']]
```

As `dhaka` and `kotwali` exists in both of 1st two lists as well as `comparable_lst`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple list comprehension:

```
nested_lists = [['what',
  'selection',
  'in',
  'dhaka'],
 ['emergency',
  'donors',
  'in',
  'kotwali',
  'posts'],
 ['the',
  'threat',
  'monsoon',
  'progresses',
  'hitting',
  ]]

words = ['dhaka',
 'kotwali',
 'khilkhet',
 'khilgaon',
 'demra',
 'turag']

want = list(l for l in nested_lists if any(w in l for w in words))

print(want)
```

Output:

```
[['what', 'selection', 'in', 'dhaka'], ['emergency', 'donors', 'in', 'kotwali', 'posts']]
```

Use the `any` function to figure out if any value in `words` is present in the `nested_lists`